# Button(MUI) not working in all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

In my file i have a button from MUI.

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

<Box m={2} px={2} width={350}>
    <Button variant="contained">Text</Button>
</Box>
```

And my output:

[image: screenshot current output]

It should look like this:

[image: screenshot expected output]

ref: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/

The colors works as they should, and if I inspect, it got a lot of MUI CSS-classes on the button. And in other components/views the button works as it should.

I've tried the following:

- Reinstalled MUI
- Copied code from MUI doc

UPDATE:
change this: `import { Container, Box, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';`
to this: `import { IconButton, Container, Box } from '@mui/material';`
and it worked as it should :)

guess the autoimport is fooling me :)
(only IconButton needed to be change, he got some base style when imported from core which overright my Button)

Comment: How does it not work as expected?

Comment: updated question with images how it should look.

Comment: Is there maybe a CSS class in that specific component, which affects the button to be different?

Comment: If I look at one component where it works and in the component where is dosent work. I found that in the component where it dosent work , the Button reads a class called: *MuiButtonBase-root*, And if i disable all properties during inspection in chrome, it looks as it should. Only need to find out why this is.

Comment: change this: import { Container, Box, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

to this: import { IconButton, Container, Box } from '@mui/material';

and it worked as it should :)
 
guess the autoimport is fooling me :) 
(only IconButton needed to be change,)

Comment: It sounds like you had the correct package installed—`@mui/material`—but were trying to import from the older package, which was called `@material-ui/core`. The naming changed from Material UI v4 —> v5 in 2021.